# getting rows at a certain date and a fixed time in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a date in the following format : `('Y-m-d')`
I'm trying to do a query that brings all rows in a certain date but only from 12:00 AM to 1:00 AM

The following will bring the required data but for today. I need the same but for the entered date `$sel_date`. How can I replace the carbon::now() with $sel_date ?

```
->whereBetween('created_at', [
             \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00'),
             \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHours(1)->format('Y-m-d 01:00:00')
                    ])
```

Comment: Edit the question and add the `$sel_date` variable

Comment: If you're specifying the hour, you don't need to do `addHours(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
->whereBetween('created_at', [
             \Carbon\Carbon::parse($sel_date)->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00'),
             \Carbon\Carbon::parse($sel_date)->addHours(1)->format('Y-m-d 01:00:00')
                    ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add 12 hours for 12 am and 1 hour for 1 am to a created instance of carbon from your date variable

Given this user object for example

```php
=> App\User {#3065
     id: 1,
     name: "something",
     email: "earlene79@example.com",
     email_verified_at: null,
     created_at: "2019-10-17 13:16:25",
     updated_at: "2019-10-17 13:16:25",
   }
```

This query returns it

```php
$sel_date = '2019-10-17';
return User::whereBetween('created_at', [
    Carbon::createFromDate($sel_date)->addHours(13),
    Carbon::createFromDate($sel_date)->addHours(14),
])->get();
```

Hope this helps